# Cassandra Key Cache Building

Tags: java, cassandra

I've inserted data into a Cassandra cluster using bulkLoader and the key caches haven't been built. Is there a way to rebuild the whole key cache for each node? I can't find an option in JMX, nodetool or OpsCenter. I'd like to avoid running a read on every key in the cluster as I'd be looking at a 25 hour+ operation.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own problem. I did end up having to do a full read of the database, but have managed to optimize it to run much faster than initially feared. To do so I created cqlsh scripts on each node that split the entire range of primary keys evenly. Managed to completely rebuild the key cache in a few hours.